# Pre-image of conjugate subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi : G \longrightarrow H$ be an epimorphism. If $W$ and $K$ are cojugate in $H$ then $\phi^{-1}(W)$ and $\phi^{-1}(K)$ are conjugate in $G$.

Firstly is this true for the above condtions?

I proceed by letting $x\in H$ such that $xWx^{-1}=K$. Now since $\phi$ is onto then $x=\phi(g)$ for some $g\in G$. I know that $\phi(\phi^{-1}(W)) = W$

So $\phi^{-1}(\phi(g)W\phi(g^{-1})) = \phi^{-1}(K)$ $\implies$  $\phi^{-1}(\phi(g\phi^{-1}(W)g^{-1}) = \phi^{-1}(K)$. I'm not sure how to proceed?

Comment: what is an episomorphism?

Comment: It is true and straightforward to prove that $g\phi^{-1}(W)g = \phi^{-1}(K)$. Just do the normal thing and show that any element of the LHS is in the RHS and vice versa.

Comment: @M.Van Epimorphism = surjective homomorphism. Monomorphism = injective homomorphism.